# How to find sentences exemplifying a secondary rarer definition?

Tags: discussion

Please beware that I ask this in general, and not only for 'such as'.
[User 'TRomano' 's comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51643/my-rewrites-of-sentences-exemplifying-alternate-and-archaic-meanings-of-such-as?noredirect=1#comment96111_51643) inspires this question. I've tried to find (superlative) sentences exemplifying the scarcer definitions 2 and 3. So if I simply input or look up 'such as',  the results will instantiate only definition 1 which I ask NOT about. I did try ODO, but in many instances, the quantity of example sentences falls short; there are no more than 3 or 4, such as for [Definition 3 of **such as**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/such-as?q=such+as).

Comment: Ngrams, Google books' comparisons and simply Googling them is my method.

Comment: But I figure, as you dig a lot into archaic English, things are just harder for you.

Comment: Say, wouldn't this be more helpful on the main site? The language is best learned through real use, not through definitions. I would think that almost any advanced EFL learner could benefit from knowing some tips on finding real use of terms, especially in unusual senses.

Comment: @BenKovitz - Perhaps you're right. I was a bit torn on this one when I migrated it. I think I'd be more inclined to move it back to the main site if more context were provided in the question. (As it is now, you need to visit at least two other links to figure out what is being asked about – the comment and the dictionary – and the comment is rather vague, meaning even more detective work needs to be done.)

Comment: @J.R. Good point about the question requiring too much "homework" on the part of the reader to understand. Unless someone beats me to it, I'll rewrite the question, probably taking more liberties than usual. (But not before I get some more schoolwork done tonight.)

Comment: @TRomano Would you please undelete your answer, or elsewhere in which you can post it, because it truly helps? Please advise how I can help with this.

Answer (score 2):

I often use [Your Dictionary's sentence examples](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/) to get inspiration for example sentences when I'm writing an answer, but I don't know how suitable it is for a learner, because it isn't organized by definition. Also, because anyone can suggest an example, I've seen some bad ones and the voting doesn't seem to sort the bad examples out quite as readily as bad answers get downvoted on SE sites.

[Reference.com](http://www.reference.com/example-sentences/such-as) also has example sentences, but again, they aren't grouped according to definitions.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I imagined when I decided to migrate the question. This question could be interpreted as a "request for resources" question, which is often handled on [meta](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english).